# How to conversion of a boxed double type to int value type?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am reading a book to pass the Microsoft Exam 70-483 and I got a little stuck on the following question :

The following code is boxed into object o.

```
double d = 11.5;
object o = d;
```

You’re asked to cast object o into int. What option should you use in your code?

```
int i = (int)o; //Option : A
int i = (int)(double)o;     //Option : B
int i = (int)(float)(double)o; //Option : C
int i = (float)o;     //Option : D
```

According to book, true answer is C, but I could not understand why the option b is wrong. When I try to run both of them, results are the same. Is there any difference option B and option C? What are your opinions?

Comment: The book is The C# Programmer's Study Guide (MCSD). Exam: 70-483. Authors: Asad, Ali, Ali, Hamza

Comment: Well, A would fail ("Specified cast is not valid."), and D would also fail ("Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'.")  
So your only options are B and C. Between them, I really don't see a difference.

Comment: I think it's due to **custom sequences of instructions**. For more information visit the link given below: [https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your given example, option B is totally fine.

Option A: You can't box and unbox different types. This will result in an `InvalidCastException`.

Option B: Totally fine. `o` will be unboxed in a `double`. Afterwards it will be cast (explicit) in an `integer`.

Option C: Like B, but before casting it into an integer, it will be casted to an float. The Result will stay the same. There is absolutly no need for the cast from double to float. It will always truncate.
But there are edges cases! (See below)

Option D: Can't use implicit cast from float to int. Same as A: InvalidCastException

So why C?
There are cases where rounding a double to an int differs from rounding a float to an int.
See the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11586688/1892523) from [supercat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363751/supercat)

You can reproduce this by the following example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double val = 12344321.4999999991;
    int a = (int)(float)val;
    int b = (int)val;

    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output will be:

```
12344322
12344321
```

So as you can see, casting to float first, will result in a different outcome.
Keep in mind, that these are edge cases and most likely academic problems.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I can see the difference between two opptions although question has faulty.

Comment: It would be nice, if there exists an explanation why this is the prefered answer. Especially when there are 2 very similar cases.
Like in the example above, it is arguable whether or not 12344322 is a "better" result than 12344321 in terms of comprehensibility.